# Where does CameraView.takePicture() send the captured image bytes to?

Tags: java, android

I'm going through the messaging app Signal's android code and I'm trying to see where the captured image bytes are sent to.

```
  public void takePicture(final Rect previewRect) {
if (!camera.isPresent() || camera.get().getParameters() == null) {
  Log.w(TAG, "camera not in capture-ready state");
  return;
}

camera.get().setOneShotPreviewCallback(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
  @Override
  public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, final Camera camera) {
    final int  rotation     = getCameraPictureOrientation();
    final Size previewSize  = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
    final Rect croppingRect = getCroppedRect(previewSize, previewRect, rotation);

    Log.w(TAG, "previewSize: " + previewSize.width + "x" + previewSize.height);
    Log.w(TAG, "data bytes: " + data.length);
    Log.w(TAG, "previewFormat: " + camera.getParameters().getPreviewFormat());
    Log.w(TAG, "croppingRect: " + croppingRect.toString());
    Log.w(TAG, "rotation: " + rotation);
    new CaptureTask(previewSize, rotation, croppingRect).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, data);
  }
});
}
```

Is it being sent to CaptureTask constructor? I'm particularly interested in when/where the image is written to storage. Here's the link to relevant part of the code: [CameraView.java](https://github.com/WhisperSystems/Signal-Android/blob/master/src/org/thoughtcrime/securesms/components/camera/CameraView.java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to see where the captured image bytes are sent to.

The captured image bytes are the `byte[] data`. `data` is passed to `executeOnExecutor()`. `CaptureTask` is an `AsyncTask`; the `byte[]` is passed to `doInBackground()`.

Comment: Thank you, how do I know (or rather how did you know) it is passed to `doInBackground()`? Is it because that is the way it is defined in the Android API?

Comment: @tinkuge: That's how `AsyncTask` works. [The `AsyncTask` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) covers this, but not especially well. But most books and courses on Android app development will have material on `AsyncTask` and would get into this topic.